# How to fetch JSON value into my Facebook android application

Tags: android, json

I have been looking for some code for fetching JSON value into my Facebook android application.

My query is:

I have a ImageView and 2 Text Views. In ImageView i display the image of the user, and in TextView i display the Name of the User and his Message. I get the JSON data as a JSON Object. I am able to display the entire data as such when i use webview to display the contents. But i am trying to  split the JSON data returned from service and display it in corresponding Imageview and Textviews instead of using WebView.

How can i seperate the JSON value returned from service and display them in corresponding fields.

I need help in solving this issue.

Exactly like displaying the new feeds in Facebook for Android. Any sample code will be of great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to parse your json result in the string and then display that string in appropriate fields...

Comment: I cant understand the problem, if you google "android json" you will find a lot of information on how to parse json :) you can also find a lot of information on displaying views if you go to developer.android.com... Have you even tried searching before making this thread? :)

Comment: hi, I googled many a sites. I was unable to understand y i get HTML response from JSON service rather that JSON array. I need a sample code to run Facebook application in my Android application. Please suggest me few links where i can find sample project for FB in Android  application. I shall be thankful to u.

Comment: you need to rewrite your question, at first you say you want to get help with displaying the json array in the same way facebook displays statuses and now you want a facebook app sample... rethink and tell us exactly whats your problem and what you want...

Comment: I need to create a sample FB application in my android application. I need a best sample code to display all the feeds from my FB. A working FB sample will be of great help.